Trying to configure azure storage account as backend in terraform to store terraform state file
Getting this error while running Terraform init in Terraform workspace after adding bacend storage account

Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthenticationFailed" Message="Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:0864061c-701e-0017-7181-ff8336000000\nTime:2024-09-05T10:50:32.8389625Z"

I have tried to store terraform state file to backend azure storage and added necessary permissions to the service principle id but unable to store the file to storage account

Please show us how you're configuring the backend. Which authentication method are you using? See https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm

do your service principle has blob storage contributor role permission on storgae account? @gopichand

This looks like an Authentication error.
You need to setup the backend like this
backend setup
You can follow this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage?tabs=terraform
login with your service principal with az cli command -
az login --service-principal -u "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -p "your-client-secret" --tenant "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
Also, check that your service principal has neccessary roles
It's good to give contributor role(as you will be deploying resources) to service principal on subscription
Follow this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-service-principal-portal
